# Update Function does not work properly Android Studio SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

I made a simple app to test the update function. The main page (recyclerView_Activity) is where the data from the database show up. My insert function works just fine. Data is inserted successully and the it appears in the recyclerView. The update function is half functional. The Toast message appears 'Successfully Updated!', but nothing changes in the recyclerView.

Here is the main page recyclerView_Activity:

```
package com.example.db_app;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class recyclerView_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button insertBtn;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DBHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<String> temp_id, temp_input;
    myAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        insertBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insertBtn);

        insertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(recyclerView_Activity.this, Insert_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        myDB = new DBHelper(recyclerView_Activity.this);

        temp_id = new ArrayList<>();
        temp_input = new ArrayList<>();

        storeDataInArrays();

        myAdapter = new myAdapter(recyclerView_Activity.this, this, temp_id, temp_input);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView_Activity.this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1)
        {
            recreate();
        }
    }

    void storeDataInArrays() {
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readData();  // Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();

        if (cursor.getCount() == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(recyclerView_Activity.this, "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            temp_id.add(cursor.getString(0));
            temp_input.add(cursor.getString(1));


        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the Insert Activity

```
package com.example.db_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Insert_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText input;
    Button insert;
    String temp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert);

        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insertBtn);

        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DBHelper db = new DBHelper(Insert_Activity.this);
                temp = input.getText().toString().trim();
                db.insertData(temp);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Insert_Activity.this, recyclerView_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Here is the Update Activity

```
package com.example.db_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Update_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText input;
    Button update;

    String id, temp, input2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateBtn);

        getAndSetIntentData();

        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DBHelper db = new DBHelper(Update_Activity.this);
                temp = input.getText().toString().trim();
                db.updateData(id, temp);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Update_Activity.this, recyclerView_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    void getAndSetIntentData() {
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("id") && getIntent().hasExtra("input2"))
        {
            // Getting data from Intent
            id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
            input2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("input2");


            // Setting Intent Data
            input.setText(input2);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Update_Activity.this, "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The Database Helper Class

```
package com.example.db_app;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.nio.file.LinkPermission;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Database.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Create table
    private static final String TABLE_TEMP = "TEMPP";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_INPUT = "input";

    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String profileQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEMP +
                " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_INPUT + " TEXT " + ")";
        db.execSQL(profileQuery);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TEMP);
        onCreate(db);


    }

    // Functions for TEMP TABLE ********************************************************************************************************************************************  PROFILE TEMP
    public Boolean insertData(String input) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_INPUT, input);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_TEMP, null, cv);

        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Insert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return  false;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Data Inserted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }

    Cursor readData() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TEMP;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;

        if (db != null) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    // Update data using where clause;
    public Boolean updateData(String row_id, String input)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_INPUT, input);

        long result = db.update(TABLE_TEMP, cv, COLUMN_ID + " =? ", new String[]{row_id});
        //long result = db.update(TABLE_TEMP, cv, "_id=? ", new String[]{row_id});
        //  db.update("Items", contentValues, whereClause, whereArgs);

        if (result == -1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Update",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Updated!",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

    }


}
```

And the Adapter

```
package com.example.db_app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    Activity activity;
    private ArrayList id, input;

    myAdapter(Activity activity,Context context, ArrayList id, ArrayList input) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.id = id;
        this.input = input;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.id_txt.setText(String.valueOf(id.get(position)));
        holder.input_txt.setText(String.valueOf(input.get(position)));
        holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Update_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("input", String.valueOf(input.get(position)));
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return id.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView id_txt, input_txt;
        LinearLayout mainLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            id_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_txt);
            input_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.input_txt);
            mainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        }
    }
}
```

I apologise if I entered too much details. I really didn't know how much info was necessary .
I followed tutorials. I even based this code based on a tutorial, and even though the code is basicaly the same, the update function just doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with C++ and Android Studio. It is about SQLite and Java, so don't set irrelevant tags.

Comment: I added c++ by accident sorry. This project is made in Android Studio, how is it irrelevant? I am asking so I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: The question is not about how to use Android Studio, so it is irrelevant. If you want you can set the `android` tag.

Comment: Oh okay I understand. Thank you for explaining